# Deploy contract to local hardhat node with forked Kovan chain

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am trying to write tests for my contract on Kovan network. In order to do so I am using the fork feature of hardhat and added the following to the `hardhat.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.0",
  defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: INFURA_URL,
        accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`]
      }
    }
  }
};
```

INFURA_URL points to node on Kovan. PRIVATE_KEY is the key of an account on Kovan I would like to deploy with. This variables work well when I deploy to Kovan directly but not to forked node.

In my deployment script I do the following:

```
const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

But my `deployer` is not the account that corresponds to the private key from config. It is a correct account when I deploy directly to Kovan.

Not sure why does this happen are forks of Kovan not supported on hardhat?

Comment: probably not relevant but, it is supposed to be like this: `accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]`. You don't have to add `0x`.

Comment: Thank you, that is a little more convenient but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked for me was to forget Hardhat and rely entirely on `ethers`, for that I created a `Signer` specifying a private key and a provider like:

```js
import { providers, Wallet } from 'ethers';
require('dotenv').config();

const main = async() => {
  const providerLocal = new 
  providers.JsonRpcProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545");
  const owner = new Wallet(process.env.DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY as string, providerLocal);
  console.log(`The wallet ${owner.address} will deploy this contract`)

  const MyContract = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyContract');
  const mycontract = await MayContract.connect(owner).deploy();
}

main();
```